# Issue in loading AngularJs 2 typescript files

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular, typescript1.8

I'm getting the below typescript errors as shown in figures , all are typescript files related errors like property doesnot exist and Cannot find names.

[image: Angular 2 TYpescript errors]

Comment: you need to install typings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `tsconfig.json` exclude the `node_modules` folder

```
  {
      "compilerOptions": {

        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,

        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "watch":true
      },
      "compileOnSave": true,
      "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "typings/main",
        "typings/main.d.ts",

        "typings"
      ]
    }
```